# I connect in the database but the values does not change when I give UPDATE MYSQL Qt C ++

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, user-interface, qt4

I am able to insert, fetch all data and delete a data in MYSQL database but I can not make the change (UPDATE), I am connecting in the database, all right, when I change the data in the table and click on the update button, I get the Data updated and quardar in the sql query, but when I run the query, it does not change / update any value in the database

Connection to the bank (ok):

```js
void ConectaBanco()
{
    //Variavel do tipo DataBase
    QSqlDatabase db;

    //Conexao com o MYSQL
    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");

    //Servidor que vai receber o DB (padrão do server local)
    db.setHostName("127.0.0.1");

    //Porta que vai conectar com o DB (por padrão vai ser 3306)
    db.setPort(3306);

    //Seleciona o banco de dados
    db.setDatabaseName("cursos");

    //Usuario do BD
    db.setUserName("root");

    //Caso tenha senha no mysql
    //db.setPassword();

    //Teste de conexao
    if(db.open())
    {
        qDebug()<<"Sucesso ao abrir a conexão";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()<<db.lastError().text();
    }
}
```

Update function:

```js
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    int fila = 0;
    ConectaBanco();
    int CdAluno = ui->tabelaCarga->model()->data(ui->tabelaCarga->model()->index(fila,0)).toInt();
    QString NmAluno = ui->tabelaCarga->model()->data(ui->tabelaCarga->model()->index(fila,1)).toString();
    QString NmCurso = ui->tabelaCarga->model()->data(ui->tabelaCarga->model()->index(fila,2)).toString();
    QString NmEscola = ui->tabelaCarga->model()->data(ui->tabelaCarga->model()->index(fila,3)).toString();


    QSqlQuery query("UPDATE matricula set NmAluno= '"+NmAluno+"', "
                                         "NmCurso= '"+NmCurso+"', "
                                         "NmEscola='"+NmEscola+"' "
                                         "WHERE CdMatricula='"+CdAluno+"'");
    query.exec();

}
```

I would like to know how to solve the problem and be able to change the data perfectly.

Comment: You should be using bindValue to prevent injection. CdAluno should not be quoted if CdMatricula is an int.  No errors and no update would indicate the WHERE clause is not satisfied.

Comment: How do I do this friend?

Comment: add "WHERE" in your sql query example: "WHERE id = 1" where "id" is primary key

Comment: What does `exec()` return, also what is the actual error message? See `QSqlQuery::lastError()`.